# pushing custom variables with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am using GA code on my website like below

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
                    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxx-1']);
                    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.myweb.co.uk']);
if (source != '') {
                        _gaq.push(function() {
                            extga._setCampValues(source, medium, name);
                        });
                    }
                    // Set the custom variable ranking
                    var url = String(document.referrer);
                    // confirm they came from G
                    if (url.indexOf("google.co") != -1 || url.indexOf("google.be") != -1 || url.indexOf("google.ie") != -1 || url.indexOf("google.fr") != -1) {

                        var urlVars = {};
                        var parts = url.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m, key, value) {
                            urlVars[key] = value;
                        });
                        // Push to GA Custom Variables
                        _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', '1', 'Keywords Rankings', urlVars["cd"], 1]);
                    }
                    //Track the record in GA
                    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

                    (function() {
                        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
                        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
                    })();
                </script>
```

Now i want to replace GA code with Google Tag Manager. My question is that how we can push cstom variables on google analytics while using google tag managera, currently i am pushing custom data for campaign with _gaq.push methods.

Regards,
Habib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to use a Custom Javascript Macro to handle the custom variable. You could put your entire set custom variable ranking within it:

```
function(){
var url = {{referrer}}; //there is a GTM macro for the HTTP referrer

// confirm they came from G
if (url.indexOf("google.co") != -1 || url.indexOf("google.be") != -1 || url.indexOf("google.ie") != -1 || url.indexOf("google.fr") != -1) {

    var urlVars = {};

    var parts = url.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m, key, value) {
        urlVars[key] = value;
    });

// Return the Custom Variable value
return urlVars["cd"];
}
```

}

*Note, I didn't test this code, but it should be pretty close.

Then you can use that macro, you'd probably name it something like {{customVar1Val}} and plug that into Google Analytics tag:

[image]

Comment: Hi I also use   _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/activity-weekends/enquiry/']); to push custom goals to GA how can we handle this in GTM. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Once you move to Google Tag Manager, replace your `_gaq.push()` with `dataLayer.push()`.
Internally, dataLayer.push() calls _gaq.push() when a tag's firing rule is triggered.

Create a Google Analytics `tag` and configure with your account, domain name etc. By default, it runs on all pages using a firing `rule`.

You can either use the GUI for managing the GA configuration, or just use a custom html snippet and paste in your code.

You're going to want to use `macros` to build up your custom variables.
Use a custom javascript macro and you can reuse your existing code.
Then include the macro in your GA tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be answered at the [Tag Manager developers guide](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide). There is even a section called [Migrating Tags to Google Tag Manager](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#migration) where you can read

> ... This section describes a best practice migration workflow. The process has 5 main steps:
>
> 1. Map your site (optional)
> 2. List item
> 3. Implement standard Google Tag Manager snippet
> 4. Add Events and Variables
> 5. Add tags with associated firing rules in Google Tag Manager's management interface
> 6. Final migration swap